# How to get Solr to use a logger other than root with Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, logging, solr

I have Solr 4 running in Tomcat 6. The application is running just fine, but I'm having trouble getting Tomcat to write the logs where I want. Here are the relevant parts of my `conf/logging.properties` file.

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           5solr.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

5solr.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
5solr.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /var/log/solr
5solr.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = solr.

# SNIP...

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/solr].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/solr].handlers = 5solr.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# SNIP...
```

I've snipped out the settings for `Handler`s 1 - 4, because I have not changed them from what they were when I installed Tomcat.

When I start up Tomcat, it creates the following log files.

```
$ ls -l $CATALINA_HOME/logs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webapp webapp 11836 Feb  4 18:29 catalina.2013-02-04.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webapp webapp 11836 Feb  4 18:29 catalina.out

$ ls /var/log/solr -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webapp webapp 0 Feb  4 18:29 solr.2013-02-04.log
```

The files `catalina.out` and `catalina.2013-02-04.log` contain the log output for Solr. What I was trying to do with `logging.properties` was put the Solr logs in `/var/log/solr`.

I expect what happened is that Tomcat picked up my changes to `logging.properties` and created the log file in `/var/log/solr`, but Solr's log messages are not going to the right place, and end up going all the way up to the root logger.

Solr uses SLF4J, which should be able to write logs to the `java.util.logging` interface, but Tomcat reimplements part of that interface (JULI) to allow for having a separate logger per context. Is there some incompatibility between SLF4J and JULI? How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the solr handlers to the newly added handler :-

```
org.apache.solr.level = INFO
org.apache.solr.handlers = 5solr.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Comment: This worked well for me... I was able to segregate out the Solr logs, which have been messing up all our other logging for a long, long time... Thanks!